# SelectionListener in SWT Combo

Tags: java, swt, listener

I currently have a combo where a user can choose between different heading options to apply to a text. The problem I'm having is that the selection listener gets triggered every time the user traverses through the list with arrow keys.

I found out that `widgetDefaultSelected` allows you to wait for a certain confirmation, oftentimes pressing the 'Enter' key, before the selection will be made.

```
public ComboBuilder add(String text, Consumer<TypedEvent> onSelect) {
    widget.add(text);
    final int index = widget.getItemCount() - 1;

    widget.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e){
            if (widget.getSelectionIndex() == index) {
                onSelect.accept(e);
            }
        }
    });

    return this;
}
```

This stalls out the selection but then now the user is having to hit 'Enter' twice or mouse click + 'Enter'. What is the proper way to be able to traverse through the Combo selection (with the keyboard) while not having to go through these extra steps upon selection?

Comment: It's expected that a `SelectionEvent` is triggered when traversing with the arrow keys because you are in fact making a new selection. You can't expect that the `Combo` will always be expanded via a mouse click. For example, if a user hits the `Tab` key to focus on the `Combo`, then uses the arrow keys, they have made a new selection - what were you expecting to happen in this case?

Comment: I was hoping to make it so, when tabbing to the combo and selecting with the arrow keys, that it would wait until the 'Enter' key is hit before the selection actually goes. Right now it applies the first option in the combo because selection is already triggered.

Comment: I would rethink the workflow that you're trying to achieve. It feels very non-standard, and as a user I would be a bit confused by it. What action are you performing in response to the selection event? Why do you not want that action to occur whenever a new item in the combo is selected (in the standard sense, not only when 'Enter' is pressed)? Is it a technical reason, or is there a specific workflow (bigger picture - not just the interaction with the Combo specificially) you're trying to achieve? (Comments shouldn't be for discussion, so these are just some things for you to consider)

Comment: I was hoping there would be a way to do it other than having a separate button to apply an action after selection. The way I was thinking is probably simply not a job for a Combo. Thanks for the input @avojak!

Comment: We too had similar issue. I found that this issue also exist for example in Excel too. So we made our own custom combo which doesn't fire selection listener on arrow button.